# How can print out the current time with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use the following Code to execute an export data pump.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  ind NUMBER;              -- Loop index
  h1 NUMBER;               -- Data Pump job handle
  percent_done NUMBER;     -- Percentage of job complete
  job_state VARCHAR2(30);  -- To keep track of job state
  le ku$_LogEntry;         -- For WIP and error messages
  js ku$_JobStatus;        -- The job status from get_status
  jd ku$_JobDesc;          -- The job description from get_status
  sts ku$_Status;          -- The status object returned by get_status
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>v_systimestamp TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

BEGIN

  h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT','SCHEMA',NULL,'EXAMPLE3','LATEST');

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1, 'dumpfile.dmp', 'EXPORT_DIRECTORY', NULL, DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE, 1);

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h1,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''SchemaName'')');

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h1);



  percent_done := 0;
  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_systimestamp);
    dbms_datapump.get_status(h1,
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +

           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,-1,job_state,sts);
    js := sts.job_status;

-- If the percentage done changed, display the new value.

    if js.percent_done != percent_done
    then

      dbms_output.put_line('*** Job percent done = ' ||
                           to_char(js.percent_done));
      percent_done := js.percent_done;
    end if;

-- If any work-in-progress (WIP) or error messages were received for the job,
-- display them.

   if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0)
    then

      le := sts.wip;
    else
      if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0)
      then
        le := sts.error;
      else
        le := null;
      end if;
    end if;
    if le is not null
    then
      ind := le.FIRST;
      while ind is not null loop
        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_systimestamp);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText);
        ind := le.NEXT(ind);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

-- Indicate that the job finished and detach from it.

  dbms_output.put_line('Job has completed');
  dbms_output.put_line('Final job state = ' || job_state);
  dbms_datapump.detach(h1);
END;
```

The problem is that the export takes too long. It takes 25 minutes with this SQL Code. The Size of the schema is 1.8 GB.

And I would like to find out how much time individual steps take. That's why I want to insert a timestamp in after each process step. Then I can see how long individual steps need.

I have marked the code for the timestamp with (>>>> <<<<) in the code.

The timestamp is not updating the time. I need the CURRENT time after each process. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSTIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(systimestamp);` to print the current timestamp.

Comment: If you want to use a variable like `v_systimestamp` then you will need to set it to the current time before each use. Or use `systimestamp` directly, although I would apply a format to it as the default may not be ideal. Or, have a logging procedure that writes to a log table with a `default on null` timestamp column.

Answer (score 15):

In your code, you are setting the value of v_systimestamp at the beginning of your script - this will not change throughout the script run. You can reset the value before you log like:

```
v_systimestamp TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_systimestamp)
```

or doing something like the following before and after each section you want to monitor (no variable required):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time Started: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time Ended: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here example  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

```
curDateTime  TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUR TIME '|| curDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

If a procedure you run takes a long time, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` won't help much. Well, *it will* display something, but - as you use a loop, depending on number of iterations, `DBMS_OUTPUT` might run out of buffer size or exceed number of visible lines in SQL*Plus (if you use it) and you'll lose part of the output.

Besides, you won't see a single *letter* of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` until the procedure finishes.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to use another approach - a simple logging which requires a table, a sequence and an (autonomous transaction) procedure. Here's the script:

```
CREATE TABLE a1_log
(
   id      NUMBER,
   datum   DATE,
   descr   VARCHAR2 (500)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE seqlognap START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a1_p_log (par_descr IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO a1_log
      SELECT seqlognap.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE, par_descr FROM DUAL;

   COMMIT;
END a1_p_log;
```

Then put A1_P_LOG calls into your own procedure; something like

```
begin
  a1_p_log('selecting from a large table');
  select ... into ... from ...;

  a1_p_log('entering the loop');
  while ... loop
    a1_p_log('doing something');
  end loop;

  a1_p_log('the end');
end;
```

Here's where the autonomous transaction matters - it'll commit inserts into the log table (without affecting the main transaction), so you can (in another session, of course) trace the execution, simply by repeatedly issuing

```
  SELECT *
    FROM a1_log
ORDER BY id;
```

It'll show (imaginary example):

```
1   22.05.2018 18:13:00    selecting from a large table
2   22.05.2018 18:20:07    entering the loop
3   22.05.2018 18:20:07    doing something
4   22.05.2018 18:20:08    doing something
5   22.05.2018 18:20:09    doing something
6   22.05.2018 18:20:10    the end
```

and you'll see that step 1 takes 7 minutes to execute, so - that's what you need to investigate. It means that you don't have to wait the main procedure to finish - cancel it and start working on the bottleneck. Once you fix it, run everything again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Thank you every body so much. But I dont have much experience in SQL. I like your answer and your solution. But what I have to enter in the secondcode? How should I write the loop? This procedure create an table. Have I delete the table after the each process ? Can that be a problem? Because when I Export a schema with 100 tables. Then there is 101 Tables in the export deump-file? Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that table (A1_LOG) will be part of the export. EXPDP has an option to *exclude* tables, so you can do that if you want. Or simply ignore it and have the option of progress logging in the target schema as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question. is there a way to show the progress of the data pump in a progess bar with a java application? I think the problem is that data pump procedure runs completely over oracle. But maybe there is a possibility to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: Have you done benchmarking that indicates logging to a table is faster than logging via ```DBMS_OUTPUT```` or ```FND_FILE.PUT_LINE```?  Both are viable approaches.  I would expect performance to be similar under typical circumstances, but have never tested.

Comment: If you're asking me, @alex, then: no, I haven't done any benchmarking. But I do have procedures that take a while to finish (say, 2 hours). I can't follow its execution with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE because **nothing** is displayed until procedure finishes. That's not what I want - I want to be able to see which part of the procedure has been executed, how much time that particular piece of code took, how many rows it affected (via SQL%ROWCOUNT) and write all that info into my logging table. I can query it any time I want and know what's **currently** going on.

Comment: Good point on getting feedback before the program has finished.  Thanks for offering that..